# How to handle kink in curve created with ggplot's stat_function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `stat_function` to plot regression curves for 10 different samples in one `ggplot`. The plotted curve shows a kink close to the y-axis that shouldn't be there.

I cannot determine the corresponding x-value. I tried many different Tmax values and the kink seems to stay close to the y-axis, which ever Tmax I'm trying. So I'm assuming it is a problem with `stat_function`. The Tmax that I ultimately want to use is 3500, where the kink is annoyingly obvious and seems to be around x = 50. 
I also tried plotting the `my_curve` function for the single samples using `plot()` from base R - it gave me the continuous curve I was looking for. 
I would like to use `ggplot` though. So I would highly appreciate if somebody knows whats going on there.

This is a pseudo data frame with regression coefficients and constants:

```
set.seed(2)  
regressions <- 
  data.frame(sample = factor(1:10),   
             intercept = rnorm(10, -1, 0.1),   
             sqrtTime = rnorm(10, -0.1, 0.0001),   
             Time = rnorm(10, 0.001, 0.0001),   
             b3 = rnorm(10, 0.5, 0.1),   
             x3 = rnorm(10, 7, 1))
```

The function and the plot:

```
my_curve = function(x, b0, b1, b2, b3, x3) {  
  y = b0 + b1*sqrt(x) + b2*x + b3*x3  
  return(y)  
}

ggplot(aes(x), data = data.frame(x = c(0:Tmax))) +   
  mapply(function(b0, b1, b2, b3, x3, sample){  
    stat_function(fun = my_curve, args = list(b0 = b0,  
                                           b1 = b1,  
                                           b2 = b2,  
                                           b3 = b3,  
                                           x3 = x3),  
                  aes(colour = sample))  
  },  
  b0 = regressions$intercept,  
  b1 = regressions$sqrtTime,  
  b2 = regressions$Time,  
  b3 = regressions$b3,  
  x3 = regressions$x3,  
  sample = regressions$sample  
  )
```

[ggplot with tmax = 3500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rbqf.png)

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. You can reproduce this with base graphics and will still see it.

[image: same plot with base graphics]
The curves you are plotting result in a gap in the y values between 0 and 1, therefore when a line is drawn between the values (line is the default `geom` for `stat_function`) you'll always see a kink.

If you reduce the x intervals to less than 1 (e.g. using `seq(0,tmax,by=0.001)`) the kink will be less apparent (however be careful here, this will be computationally intensive!). Otherwise, you could exclude 0 from the interval or extend the y-axis so that the angle of the kink is less apparent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It didn't really solve my problem, but made me find the argument of `stat_function` that I needed. The kink was caused by the number of x values to interpolate along, but not directly linked to the x intervals that I specified (It  wasn't at x =1 either). I was able to remove the kink by increasing `n` within `stat_function`. Thanks :)